# C# boolean capitalization

Tags: c#, python, boolean, capitalization

I'm working in python with a c# library I occasionally have to edit. In python, booleans are specified as True/False. In c#, as true/false. This is driving me crazy. Is there a way to use #define or something to make c# recognize True/False as true/false?

Comment: `public const bool True = true;`

Comment: @QualityCatalyst has your best answer, but it's bad practice all around to do this kind of thing (it will confuse anyone who reads your code). Just use `True` and `False` like a good Microsoft customer.

Comment: @QualityCatalyst you might think about moving that comment to an answer. That way others that search this question can find the answer a little easier.

Comment: I agree. Pad it a bit and you have a free green check.

Comment: Will do, @RedRoboHood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to declare a constant that reflects the `true` value.

```
public const bool True = true;
```

I personally wouldn't go down this path though as it seems to be more like a personal choice. It may confuse other developers and doesn't add general value.